# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Decimal'

Tags: python, django

I'm just playing around learning classes functions, etc., so I decided to create a simple function that should give me a tax amount.

This is my code so far.

```
class VAT_calculator:
    """
     A set of methods for VAT calculations.
    """

    def __init__(self, amount=None):
        self.amount = amount
        self.VAT = decimal.Decimal('0.095')

    def initialize(self):
        self.amount = 0

    def total_with_VAT(self):
        """
        Returns amount with VAT added.
        """
        if not self.amount:
            msg = u"Cannot add VAT if no amount is passed!'"
            raise ValidationError(msg)

        return (self.amount * self.VAT).quantize(self.amount, rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP)
```

My issue is I'm getting the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Decimal'**

Why should this not work?

Comment: Maybe the designer is trying make you think what your really want: float or decimal (more precise definition of precision), decimal.Decimal(0.77)*2
Decimal('1.540000000000000035527136788') is fine, integer automatically promoted to decimal; but >>> decimal.Decimal(0.77)*0.78
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
make a crash.  I guess this force you to cast float into decimal if you want decimal result, and cast decimal into float if you don't care about the precision.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It seems like `self.VAT` is of `decimal.Decimal` type and `self.amount` is a `float`, a thing that you can't do.

Try `decimal.Decimal(self.amount) * self.VAT` instead.

Comment: float, decimal, same thing tho? What should I be using for currency?

Comment: It is the other way around; `self.VAT = decimal.Decimal('0.095')`.

Comment: @Spike: No, `decimal.Decimal()` is not the same thing as a `float`. It is a different approach to handling real numbers by computers.

Comment: Unable to convert 4.9 to Decimal with decimal.Decimal(self.amount) and vat is already decimal.Decimal('0.095')

Comment: @Spike: Did you put (`decimal.Decimal(self.amount)`) in the `quantize` call too?

Comment: yes but that gives quantize result has too many digits for current context

Answer (score 22):

Your issue is, as the error says, that you're trying to multiply a `Decimal` by a `float`

The simplest solution is to rewrite any reference to `amount` declaring it as a Decimal object:

`self.amount = decimal.Decimal(float(amount))`

and in `initialize`:

`self.amount = decimal.Decimal('0.0')`

Another option would be to declare Decimals in your final line:

`return (decimal.Decimal(float(self.amount)) * self.VAT).quantize(decimal.Decimal(float(self.amount)), rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP)`

...but that seems messier.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on this line of code:

```
row_value = float(row['hours']) * 0.2
```

and changed it to this:

```
row_value = float(row['hours']) * float(0.2)
```

which worked fine.

Comment: How is this an answer? `float()` is a no-op here.

Comment: Can you provide full (but minimal) code to reproduce it? Is it some [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) thing?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably left the building: *"Last seen more than a month ago"*