# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got this line of code:

```
    result = "%.2f" % round(ptos + (0.4*tcConv) - (0.7*tcInt) - (0.4*ft) + (0.7*bx["reb_of"])
    + (0.3*bx["reb_def"]) + bx["steals"] + (0.7*bx["assists"]) + (0.7*bx["block_shots"])
    - (0.4*bx["fouls_cm"]) - bx["turnovers"], 2)
```

And the exception throwed is:

```
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/com/statistics/advanced/player_advanced_stats.py", line 100, in set_game_score
    - (0.4*bx["fouls_cm"]) - bx["turnovers"], 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'
```

bx["fouls_cm"] contains number 6. If I make this float with float function, I'm still getting the same error!!!

```
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/com/statistics/advanced/player_advanced_stats.py", line 100, in set_game_score
    - (0.4*float(bx["fouls_cm"])) - bx["turnovers"], 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'
```

The solution explained in this post doesn't resolve my problem: [unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Decimal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105485/unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-decimal)

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

Comment: 0.7 * float( bx["steals"])

Comment: Note that the traceback just points at the end of the *expression*, not the *line* in which the error occurs. Which of the other values in the expression are a `Decimal` instance?

Comment: No idea where your decimals are since you haven't shared your complete code but `0.4`, `0.7`, `0.3` are all `float` which you can't mix with `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unsupported operand type(s) for \*: 'float' and 'Decimal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105485/unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-decimal)

Comment: Since ``Decimal`` is usually used for precision, is there a reason why you try to fix the problem by *removing* precision from the decimals (by conversion to ``float``) instead of *adding* precision to the floats (by making them ``Decimal``s)?

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi!!! I believed that the precision of float was higher than Decimal. But I have read that is more accurate to use Decimal. But to use Decimal has a cost and the cost is that is 3 times slower than float. Dispite of this cost I will change all my floats to decimals

Answer (score -1):

How said @MisterMiyagi the traceback only point to the end of the expression not the line which occurs the error

So the solution is to convert to float all the decimals not only bx["fouls_cm"]

The correct line of code is:

```
result = "%.2f" % round(ptos + (0.4*float(tcConv)) - (0.7*float(tcInt)) - (0.4*float(ft)) + (0.7*float(bx["reb_of"]))
+ (0.3*float(bx["reb_def"])) + bx["steals"] + (0.7*float(bx["assists"])) + (0.7*float(bx["block_shots"]))
- (0.4*float(bx["fouls_cm"])) - bx["turnovers"], 2)
```

Comment: Since this is obviously a finance application, everything should be converted to `Decimal` not `float`, to preserve accuracy in the decimal system.